# VSCode c# autocomplete not working on an added package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, nuget-package

I am trying to build a library on top of and other library / framework. 
I am doing this in C#, So at first i create a new project by doing

```
dotnet new console
```

Then i add the package which will serve as the basis for my library. I do this in the following way:

```
dotnet add package Veldrid
```

This works fine, i see it get added and it is visible in the `.csproj`

But then when i try to acces a function of a class or even create a new instance of a class from that package i see no autocomplete options what so ever :( But when i type my own class within the project its namespace autocomplete works all fine.

Why doesnt the autocomplete function work for added packages?

Extra information:

i am using a mac,
I have dotnet core 2.2.300 installed,
i am using vscode with the c# extension,
and in my project i have the `using Veldrid` added so i can use the package.

Let me know if something is unclear or extra information is needed!

side note:
I keep getting the message: `Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details` whenever i open a c# project in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

after spending an age of googling and searching i found what was causing the problem for me.

I had unity installed which also installs the mono framework. (for me the mono framework caused all the problems). So i uninstalled unity and the removed the monoframework from my computer (mac) and all was well.

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

If there are better ways of going about this please let me know!